# SQL query regarding joins

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am working on an SQL Database project and I am supposed to find the names of authors who have written 3 or more books. My code is below. The error says the A is missing a FROM and I have tried different COUNT options. I have tried many different variations and I still can't get it to produce an output.

```
SELECT A.alastname FROM Author 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book B WHERE B.btitle = A.btitle AND B.title > 2);
```

Author contains the names and Book contains the titles, pages, etc. There is also Author_Book containing aid and bid. Do I need to use a join? I still don't understand how I can specify 3+ books without using an operator. I am not asking for an answer, just some pointers if possible :).

Comment: Commendations for you for trying to work it out yourself and not just asking for the code. You may wish to investigate the HAVING clause as another solution for only including authors with more than 3 books.

Answer (score 2):

Missing an alias.

```
SELECT A.alastname FROM Author A 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book B WHERE B.btitle = A.btitle AND B.title > 2);
```

Comment: True, but it does answer his question.

Comment: Is that for real? Is that some kind of you upvote me, I upvote you movement, and who cares if an answer even makes sense?

Comment: Not really. He asked why he was getting an specific error, and I answered him. He didn't ask for his query to be rewritten.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I am getting a different error now, but adding the "A" helped me to see where my problem lies so I can try to figure that one out now.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query is not valid SQL.

You probably meant this:

```
SELECT A.alastname
FROM Author A
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM Book B WHERE B.btitle = A.btitle) > 2
```

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I was just typing it out and didn't think about how it looked; I appreciate you correcting it!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you were missing an alias for the Author table and trying to reference it as A

```
SELECT A.alastname FROM Author as A 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book B WHERE B.btitle = A.btitle AND B.title > 2);
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteboardDev; I tried that and I still got an error, but it helped me pinpoint where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have a relation table for Author<->Book so you should use it:

```
SELECT A.alastname
FROM Author A
JOIN
(
 SELECT aid FROM Author_Book GROUP BY aid HAVING count(bid)>=3
) T
on (A.id=T.aid)
```